# How to solve the errors with NPM Install?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am getting the below errors while doing the npm install but if i do npm install --force? everything works fine in the local environment but not during the repository build as my .yaml file script has the "npm install" Can someone help me on how to fix these issues?

I have tried the below two options but not helped to resolve issue

1. npm audit fix --force
2. npm install --legacy-peer-deps

[screenshot of the error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOsHL.png)

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/localize@10.0.14
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@10.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^10.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"10.2.3" from @angular/compiler-cli@10.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^10.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^10.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1002.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@ngtools/webpack)
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"10.0.14" from @angular/localize@10.0.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   @angular/localize@"^10.0.14" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/localize@"^10.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1002.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@10.0.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"10.0.14" from @angular/localize@10.0.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!     @angular/localize@"^10.0.14" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/localize@"^10.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1002.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to remove the package-lock file & your node_modules folder
- and re-run the command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

it should be fine

Comment: I have rerun the command that you gave, now package-lock.json is recreated should I commit this file? @Eslam Abu Hugair

Comment: yes, you should, it will lock the dependencies versions for you

Comment: Before committing, I am testing with “npm install” getting the different errors. This issue is eating my mind @eslam abu hugair

Comment: this time getting below errors @Eslam Abu Hugair
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@6.2.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^10.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@10.2.7

Comment: It worked after a angular version upgrade Thanks @Eslam Abu Hugair